# Facebook notifications in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-recommendation, 13.04, notification, facebook, social

Which apps will give me facebook notifications in Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: I read somewhere about an app called **wallbox**. Its a pretty impressive facebook client for linux. But the ppa I found for it was dead... since them am looking for one that works. If you look around, maybe you can find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default application for using Twitter, Facebook, and similar feed services, is `friends` which has replaced `gwibber`.

Comment: Thx...  Install Friends via command line: `sudo apt-get install friends-app`

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a social lens installed by default in Raring. While you can’t tweet from it you can view statuses, mentions, messages, etc.

[Facebook: Visit this link for more info](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/gwibber-not-in-ubuntu-13-04-install-friends)

[Alternately you can check this out](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-friends-app-gwibber-rewritten.html)

Install Friends App (Gwibber rewritten in QML):

Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail: You can install Friends via command line:

`sudo apt-get install friends-app`